# Decode Json Object from a url in php coming from a user

Tags: php, android

hey i am making an android app where user's request in the format of json . Their request will look like this..

```
  JSONObject j = new JSONObject(createJson());
          String  url ="http://codemoirai.esy.es/test.php?UserDetails="+j;

  Where j = {"Email":"code@gmail.com","Username":"xyz","Password":"xyz"}
```

This is what I will be sending to the test.php , i want to know how i can fetch this data and display it using php.

```
  <?php
require "init1.php";



$jsonObject = $_GET["UserDetails"];
$obj = json_decode($jsonObject);
$email = $obj->Email;
 $password = $obj->Password;
.......


echo $email; //Everthing i fetch from jsonObject is null. Why?


?>
```

ThankYou, is it correct how i am fetching in php??

Comment: Basicly youre sending a string to test.php not a object. Json_decode decodes the string with json syntax to a php array Then you van iterate it with a foreach loop

Comment: Actually i did it the other way i am sorry

Answer (score 1):

In test.php you can catch the data with `$_GET['UserDetails']` then decode it with `json_decode($_GET['UserDetails')`

Then you can iterate it with a `foreach` loop

Example:

```
if(isset($_GET['UserDetails'])) {
     $details = json_decode($_GET['UserDetails']);

      foreach($details as $key => $val) {
           echo $key.' = '.$val;
      }
```

Comment: Json_decode makes it a array. Then you van iterate it with a foreach in php

Comment: it makes it as an array only if we specify as true